# Altering the value of an option (select) element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm attempting to select the selected value of a `<select>` form element, and append the value with `-R`. (This will be for regex matching later on). Anyway, so far I've tried the following:

**Attempt 1:**

```
var country = $('select[name=g_country\\['+value+'\\]]').val(); 
$('select[name=g_country\\['+value+'\\]]').find('option[value=' + value +']').val(country + '-R');
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
var country = $('select[name=g_country\\['+value+'\\]]').val();
$('select[name=g_country\\['+value+'\\]]').val(country + '-R');
```

I can tell that the selection of the correct form element (using `delete_x`, where `x` is a number) works fine, as the form elements to disable when `.select-delete` is clicked, however the value setting doesn't. The commented portion down the bottom is what I've been using to check the value of the `<select>` element post-value change (or what should be post-value change).

**Here's a link to my jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/gPF8X/11/

Any help/edits/answers will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally came up with the right selector, props to @gjohn for the idea.

Here's my final working code, that appropriately adds `-R` to the end of `g_country[x]`:

```
$('.select-delete').click( function() {
    var value = $(this).attr('id');
    value = value.replace('delete_', '');

    var country = $('select[name=g_country\\['+value+'\\]]').val();
    $('select[name=g_country\\['+value+'\\]] > option:selected').val(country + '-R');

    $('select[name=g_country\\['+value+'\\]]').attr('disabled','1');
    $('input[name=g_url\\['+value+'\\]]').attr('disabled','1');
    $(this).css('display', 'none');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $('.select-delete').click( function() {
    var value = $(this).attr('id');
    value = value.replace('delete_', '');

    var country = $('select[name=g_country\\['+value+'\\]] option:selected').val() + '-R';
     alert(country);

    $('select[name=g_country\\['+value+'\\]] option:selected').val(country);

    $('select[name=g_country\\['+value+'\\]]').attr('disabled','1');
    $('input[name=g_url\\['+value+'\\]]').attr('disabled','1');
    $(this).css('display', 'none');
    var check = $('select[name=g_country\\['+value+'\\]]').val();
    $('#test').append(check);
});
```

There is an issue with your HTML as well.

Comment: The `.text()` function works with the text inbetween html tags, what I need to do is manipulate the value, not the text within. Also, is there any chance you could point out what HTML issue I have, as it looks fine to me?

Comment: Sorry, my bad on the HTML. I must be hallucinating. Its working fine.

Comment: Updated the jquery code - it is now updating the value on the select menu.